# Displaying result with textview

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I am working on a quiz application in android where I want to display the correct answer(i.e. pre-stored answer) and the one that is selected by the user parallel to each other(whether it is correct or wrong).
Also I want that each time when a new question is displayed the radio buttons should get unselected/empty.

I have written the following code through which it is displaying the number of correct answers and wrong answers only.
Kindly help me.

```
Computer_Test1_Activity:

    package com.example.owner.cybergram;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class Computer_Test1_Activity extends Activity {

    TextView code;
    Button btnNxt;
    RadioGroup rg1;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;
    String questions[] = {"1. Generating the corresponding code is known as encoding.","2.Word processing software automatically corrects spelling &amp; grammar mistakes.","3. OBR scans a set of vertical bars of different widths for specific data","4. More pixels means sharper image.","5. E-learning softwares can reduce the use of books.","6. Inkjet printer is a non-impact printer.","7. VGA stands for Video Graphics Array.","8. A mouse is a storage device.","9. A diskette is expensive, can not be erased and cannot be reused.","10. Graphics engineers can use computers to create 3 dimensional models.","11. A series of instructions is known as ____________.","12. The programs and data that are required to be used again and again are kept in","13. Information, Electronics and Communication Technology","14. The term Bit is an acronym of","15. Numbers are stored and transmitted inside a computer in","16. Secondary memory of a computer also known as _____________.","17. Three categories of display screen technology are","18. The use of copy and paste feature in word processing is-","19. MICR stands for?","20. The 3 different type of buses used in computer are"};
    String ans[] = {"True","True","True","True","True","True","True","False","False","True","Program","Secondary memory","Information, Electronics and Communication Technology","Binary digit","Binary form","Auxiliary memory","CRT, LCD & Projection displays","To avoid typing the same content again","Magnetic Ink Character Reccognition","Address bus, Data bus & Control bus"};
    String opt[] = {"True", "False","True","False","True","False","True","False","True","False","True","False","True","False","True","False","True","False","True","False","Program","Software","Hard disk","Secondary memory","Information, Electric and Communication Technology","Information, Electronics and Communication Technology","Binary digit","Byte","ASCII code form","Binary form","Auxiliary memory","Special memory","CRT, LCD & Projection displays","CRT, LCD & LED","To avoid the mistakes","To avoid typing the same content again","Magnetic Ink Character Recognition","Magnetic Ink Card Reader","Address bus, Data bus & Control bus","Data bus, Control bus & Logical bus"};
    int flag = 0;
    public static int marks, correct, wrong;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.computertest1);


        code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeques);
        btnNxt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNxt);
        rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);

        code.setText(questions[flag]);
        rb1.setText(opt[0]);
        rb2.setText(opt[1]);
       /* Toast.makeText(this, "Negative Marks: " + ComputerActivity.tbflag,1000).show();*/

        btnNxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                RadioButton uans =   (RadioButton)findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
                // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = rg1 .getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radio button by returned id
                RadioButton rg1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);


                String ansText = uans.getText().toString();
                if (ansText.equals(ans[flag]))
                  {
                    correct++;
                  }
                     else

                  {
                    wrong++;

                  }

                flag++;
                if (flag < questions.length)
                {
                    code.setText(questions[flag]);
                    rb1.setText(opt[flag*2]);
                    rb2.setText(opt[(flag*2)+1]);
                }
                 else
                   {
                     if (ComputerActivity.tbflag)
                     {
                        marks = correct - wrong;
                     }
                         else
                      {
                        //incase of negative marks off
                        marks = correct;
                      }

                    Intent n = new      Intent(Computer_Test1_Activity.this,ComputerResultActivity.class);
                    startActivity(n);
                   }
            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Computer_Result_Activity:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class ComputerResultActivity extends Activity {
TextView result;
Button btnRestart;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.computerresult);

    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coderesult);
    btnRestart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonrestart);

    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("Correct Ans:"+ Computer_Test1_Activity.correct);
    sb.append("\n Wrong Ans:"+ Computer_Test1_Activity.wrong);
    sb.append("\n Final Score:"+ Computer_Test1_Activity.marks);
    result.setText(sb);

    Computer_Test1_Activity.correct=0;
    Computer_Test1_Activity.wrong=0;

    btnRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ComputerActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });


}

/*@Override
public boolean OnCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.computerresult, menu);
    return true;
    }*/


}
```

Kindly help me.

Comment: Have you considered Intent.putExtra when starting ComputerResultActivity? I assume that would be the way to accomplish what you're doing.

Comment: I didn't got you,what exactly are you trying to say.

Comment: sb.append("Correct Ans:"+ Computer_Test1_Activity.correct);
    sb.append("\n Wrong Ans:"+ Computer_Test1_Activity.wrong);
    sb.append("\n Final Score:"+ Computer_Test1_Activity.marks);


This part won't really work out like you'd like it to, you should put all this stuff as extra in the intent (intent.putExtra...), then in the other activity getIntent().getIntExtra()

Unticking/ticking checkboxes can be done by chkbox.toggle()

Comment: thank you it was very helpful